# Display all but current executing/running file in python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

Currently my file is able to list all of the files of a directory. However I would like the code to ignore the file which is currently running/being executed from the list.

What code or methods will I need to add my existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the current file is given to you in the special variable `__file__`, so your listing code can compare each filename against that and omit it.

For example:

```
import os

filename = os.path.basename(__file__)
for f in os.listdir('/home/you/scripts'):
    if f != filename:
        print(f)
```

Because `__file__` gives the name of the script as specified on the command line, it might contain directory elements, e.g. `scripts/foo.py`, so the `os.path.basename` is used to get just the file part, `foo.py`.

Comment: You should add an example of doing this in conjunction with (presumably) `os.listdir` or `glob.glob`

Comment: if you could give me an example of how I could use this variable, that would help me to understand how to use it.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: you might mean `os.path.dirname(__file__)` instead of `'/home/you/scripts'` i.e., OP want to enumerate files in a directory with current running file. Or `dirname, filename = os.path.split(__file__)`. Also, use `print()` (Python 3).